# Make sure that an output of a string is a certain amount of words

Tags: python-3.x, list

So I am trying to make a list of words and it randomize it and the list returns all them out but the list is 14 words and I ALWAYS want the output to be 12 words. This is extremely difficult because the len count changes, is this even possible? This is my code it runs smoothly but I don't how to remove 2 words at the end under the print because the characters change.

```
words = ["seed", "rest", "sad", "running", "water", "disease", "militia", "apple", "banana", "grape", "program", "stove", "prints", "forrest"]       
randomizing_words = random.sample(words, len(words))
linecount = len(randomizing_words)
       if linecount >= 12:
           print('removing last 2 to make it 12 words')
          # (WHAT DO I DO HERE)
       else:
           pass
```

I feel like this may be impossible. Any tips would help

Answer (score 0):

Simply return the first 12 elements of the list no matter what:

```
import random    # imports random

words = ["seed", "rest", "sad", "running", "water", "disease", "militia", "apple", "banana", "grape", "program", "stove", "prints", "forrest"]    # initial list
random.shuffle(words)    # randomizes list
print(words[:12])    # prints (you can change this to return) first 12 elements of the list
```